# Aggregate difference between time ranges in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-functions, difference

I'm on Postgres 15 and using the multirange type to aggregate overlapping time ranges into islands:

```
CREATE TABLE time_entries (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    contract_id bigint,
    "from" timestamp(6) without time zone,
    "to" timestamp(6) without time zone,
    type varchar,
    range tsrange GENERATED ALWAYS AS (tsrange("from", "to")) STORED
);

INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (1, 1, '2022-12-07T09:00', '2022-12-07T10:00', 'billed');
INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (2, 1, '2022-12-07T08:00', '2022-12-07T10:30', 'punch_clock');

INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (1, 1, '2022-12-07T12:00', '2022-12-07T12:30', 'billed');
INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (2, 1, '2022-12-07T11:30', '2022-12-07T12:15', 'punch_clock');

INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (2, 1, '2022-12-07T13:00', '2022-12-07T13:30', 'billed');
INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (2, 1, '2022-12-07T13:15', '2022-12-07T13:45', 'punch_clock');

INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (2, 1, '2022-12-07T14:00', '2022-12-07T15:00', 'punch_clock');

SELECT contract_id, unnest(range_agg(range)) AS range FROM time_entries GROUP BY contract_id;
```

Working db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/V9a7H8nJ

This results in these merged time ranges:

| contract_id | range |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 08:00:00","2022-12-07 10:30:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 11:30:00","2022-12-07 12:30:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 13:00:00","2022-12-07 13:45:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 14:00:00","2022-12-07 15:00:00") |

But now, I need another metric: The unbilled hours of a tracking. I have two types of entries `punch_clock` and `billed`. The former is a tracker that runs in the background when they are working, and the latter is a parallel tracker that runs for specific projects.

How could I calculate the *difference* between the overlapping `punch_clock` and `billed` entries?

**The desired result would be:**

| contract_id | unbilled |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 08:00:00","2022-12-07 09:00:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 10:00:00","2022-12-07 10:30:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 11:30:00","2022-12-07 12:00:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 13:30:00","2022-12-07 13:45:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 14:00:00","2022-12-07 15:00:00") |

I played around by grouping by `type`, but it seems there is no `range_difference_agg` aggregation function for multiranges, only `range_agg` for union and `range_intersect_agg` for intersections: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest you to change the definition of the `time_entries` table so that to replace the type `tsrange` of the `range` column by `tsmultirange` :

```
CREATE TABLE time_entries (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    contract_id bigint,
    "from" timestamp(6) without time zone,
    "to" timestamp(6) without time zone,
    type varchar,
    range tsmultirange GENERATED ALWAYS AS (tsmultirange(tsrange("from", "to"))) STORED
);
```

Then, according to the data sample you provide, you don't need an aggregate function. A self-join query should provide the expected result :

```
SELECT p.contract_id, unnest(CASE WHEN b.range IS NULL THEN p.range ELSE p.range - b.range END) AS unbilled
  FROM ( SELECT contract_id, range FROM time_entries WHERE type = 'punch_clock') AS p
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT contract_id, range FROM time_entries WHERE type = 'billed') AS b
    ON p.contract_id = b.contract_id
   AND p.range && b.range
```

Result :

| contract_id | unbilled |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 08:00:00","2022-12-07 09:00:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 10:00:00","2022-12-07 10:30:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 11:30:00","2022-12-07 12:00:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 13:30:00","2022-12-07 13:45:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 14:00:00","2022-12-07 15:00:00") |

This query will work while only one 'billed' timerange intersects with one 'punch_clock' time range. If several 'billed' timeranges may intersect the same 'punch_clock' time range, then you will need to create your own aggregate function based on the multirange difference operator :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multirange_diff (x anymultirange, y anymultirange, z anymultirange)
RETURNS anymultirange LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS $$
SELECT CASE WHEN x IS NULL THEN COALESCE(y-z, y) ELSE COALESCE(x-z, x) END ; $$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE multirange_diff_agg(anymultirange, anymultirange)
( stype = anymultirange, sfunc = multirange_diff) ;
```

The query using the new aggregate function is :

```
SELECT p.contract_id, unnest(multirange_diff_agg(p.range, b.range)) AS unbilled
  FROM ( SELECT contract_id, range FROM time_entries WHERE type = 'punch_clock') AS p
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT contract_id, range FROM time_entries WHERE type = 'billed') AS b
    ON p.contract_id = b.contract_id
   AND p.range && b.range
 GROUP BY p.contract_id, p.range
```

As an example, after having inserted the new row in table `time_entries` :

```
INSERT INTO time_entries VALUES (1, 1, '2022-12-07T10:10', '2022-12-07T10:20', 'billed');
```

The result of the above query is :

| contract_id | unbilled |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 08:00:00","2022-12-07 09:00:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 10:00:00","2022-12-07 10:10:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 10:20:00","2022-12-07 10:30:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 11:30:00","2022-12-07 12:00:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 13:30:00","2022-12-07 13:45:00") |
| 1 | ["2022-12-07 14:00:00","2022-12-07 15:00:00") |

**UPDATE**

Even when several 'billed' timeranges intersect the same 'punch_clock' time range, you don't need an aggregate function. The following query should provide the expected result :

```
SELECT contract_id
     , unnest ( range_agg(range) FILTER (WHERE type = 'punch_clock')
              - range_agg(range) FILTER (WHERE type = 'billed')
              ) AS unbilled
  FROM time_entries
 GROUP BY contract_id
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hPpgs-ER)

for more information about creating an aggregate function see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createaggregate.html)